# Issues getting the Address API in Play Services 4.3 to work

Tags: android, google-play-services

I've setup the Google Play Services 4.4 library in my project and I've been trying to get address picker to show. Here is my activity code to call the API ([javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/identity/intents/Address.html#requestUserAddress%28com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.identity.intents.UserAddressRequest,%20int%29)):

```
GoogleApiClient client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(Address.API).useDefaultAccount().build();
client.connect();
Address.requestUserAddress(client, null, 1000);
```

And this is my onActivityResult code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1000 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        UserAddress address = UserAddress.fromIntent(data);
        Toast.makeText(this, address.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Whenever I run the app, no picker is shown and logcat displays this:

```
05-13 14:30:43.204: D/AddressRetreiver(2489): Is cached profile null?true
05-13 14:30:43.212: W/GLSUser(2505): GoogleAccountDataService.getToken()
05-13 14:30:43.212: W/GLSActivity(2505): [apc] Status from wire: BadUsername status: BAD_USERNAME
05-13 14:30:43.216: E/GetWalletProfileTask(2489): [<<default account>>:1]GoogleAuthException when getting auth token
```

Does anyone see what is wrong with this code?

Update:

I was using an emulator with GApps installed. I tried a device and that also didn't work. Then I removed the `useDefaultAccount()` from the `GoogleApiClient.Builder` call. This worked on my device but not on my emulator. Though now Google Play Services crashes with the following log:

```
05-14 12:17:38.265: E/AndroidRuntime(10184): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-14 12:17:38.265: E/AndroidRuntime(10184): Process: com.google.android.gms.ui, PID: 10184
05-14 12:17:38.265: E/AndroidRuntime(10184): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.wallet.address.RequestUserAddressActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: null reference
05-14 12:17:38.265: E/AndroidRuntime(10184):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
05-14 12:17:38.265: E/AndroidRuntime(10184):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
05-14 12:17:38.265: E/AndroidRuntime(10184):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
05-14 12:17:38.265: E/AndroidRuntime(10184):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
05-14 12:17:38.265: E/AndroidRuntime(10184):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-14 12:17:38.265: E/AndroidRuntime(10184):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-14 12:17:38.265: E/AndroidRuntime(10184):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5149)
05-14 12:17:38.265: E/AndroidRuntime(10184):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-14 12:17:38.265: E/AndroidRuntime(10184):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-14 12:17:38.265: E/AndroidRuntime(10184):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
05-14 12:17:38.265: E/AndroidRuntime(10184):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
05-14 12:17:38.265: E/AndroidRuntime(10184):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-14 12:17:38.265: E/AndroidRuntime(10184): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null reference
05-14 12:17:38.265: E/AndroidRuntime(10184):    at bkm.a(SourceFile:27)
05-14 12:17:38.265: E/AndroidRuntime(10184):    at com.google.android.gms.wallet.address.RequestUserAddressActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:106)
05-14 12:17:38.265: E/AndroidRuntime(10184):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-14 12:17:38.265: E/AndroidRuntime(10184):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-14 12:17:38.265: E/AndroidRuntime(10184):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
05-14 12:17:38.265: E/AndroidRuntime(10184):    ... 11 more
```

Seems to be an issue with the library.

Comment: Google developer site says that you must not pass null in the parameter.